# "Ни в зуб ногой" — происхождение фразеологизма

Tags: этимология, фразеология

И еще один фразеологизм.
***"Ни в зуб ногой"***  — так говорят, когда в чем-то вообще не разбираются, чего-то не знают.

Странное какое-то выражение. *Причем тут драка* (а речь, как я понимаю, именно о драке) *и отсутствие знаний по какому-то вопросу?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ Грамоты.ру (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/phrases/?page=3&alpha=%CD   ):

Ни в зуб ногой - разговорно-просторечное, иронич.: совершенно ничего не знать, не понимать, не смыслить в чем-нибудь, абсолютно не разбираться в чем-нибудь.
Существует несколько версий происхождения этого фразеологизма.

1. Этот оборот - усечение более пространного выражения ни в зуб толкнуть не смыслит, которое употреблялось в 19 в. Оборот относится ко времени крепостничества, и его первоначальное значение соответствовало духу времени: "при надобности дажа дать зуботычину не умеет", позже - 'ни к чему не годен, ничего не умеет', а потом и как синоним выражения ни аза.
2. Оборот ни в зуб толкнуть из школьного жаргона. Вариант ни в зуб ногой - более позднее образование, возникло в результате сближения двух фразеологизмов ни в зуб (толкнуть) + ни ногой (куда, где). Развитие у фразеологизма ни ногой куда, где значения 'не бывать, не заниматься и, следовательно, ничего не знать' стало основанием для сближения с фразеологизмом ни в зуб и привело к формированию современного значения.
3. Выражение собственно русское, из школьного арго. Употребляется в русском языке с 19 в. Вероятно, связано с забавой детей - подведением большого пальца ноги ко рту - и подтруниванием над теми, кто не мог этого делать.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего, опять под влиянием времени и разного произношения фразы получился такой фразеологизм. Знания "НА ЗУБОК", мне кажется, эти выражения взаимосвязаны... "Чтоб от зубов отлетало...", а тут хоть "в зуб ногой", всё равно ничего не скажет. Ну что-то вроде "хоть кол на голове теши" - тоже, ещё то выражение.

Answer (score -1):

Мне представляется логичным объединение пп.1 и 2 с *Грамоты.ru.*
***"Ни в зуб", "ни ногой"***  — при надобности не сможет ни зуботычины дать, ни пинка.
Превратилось в "ни в зуб ногой".